# Parsing structured documents in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I would like to parse some legal documents with a Java library into pieces of text that represent headers, paragraphs etc. Legal documents are usually well-structured, so I would like to use something a bit easier than JavaCC (or other parser generators). Are there any which would allow to (nearly) automatically detect such a structure?

Thanks.

Comment: what format are these docs in? pdf? .doc?

Comment: +1 to Richard. What's the format?

Comment: Could be anything: plain text, doc, html etc. I would like to convert it to the plain text to analyze it further.

Comment: I do understand that it is much easier to have it all in html, because mark-up can be analazed and the whole structure of the document can be figured out based on that. What I mean actually is a plain text document without any "hints" on e.g. where the next chapter starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no tool that can "nearly automatically" extract such structures. If it is realy easy to extract the structure you would not need any tool, you can easely code it yourself. If it is not so easy you need a tool that is powerfull enough (JavaCC, ANTLR ...).

I think parsing the text yourself with custom code is the best way. Maybe read beforehand a bit about parsing (recursive decent, lexer/parser seperation...). For simple structures it is not hard to get a working solution quickly.

Comment: Currently I am almost sure that I will need JavaCC. But maybe I can simplify this by bringing in a two-step process: rough parsing  according to custom grammar and then the final clean-up with some other tool...

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) - the Java API for Microsoft Documents
[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) - Java PDF Library

easier one will be [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) - a content analysis toolkit, toolkit for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.

it uses pdfbox and poi internally

use: java -jar tika-app-0.9.jar [option] [file] -t

will parse the file(s) specified on the
  command line and output the extracted text content

Comment: I have read something about it but didn't get how it is able to extract structured information. Does it look at the pieces of text which have several occurences in the entire document?

Comment: tika will parse the documents, ie text inside the document will be will output as text. i think format settings will also be exported as extra if any. try out some examples. it will export meta data in a clean fashion